# Is "Don't you know? " the same as "Do not you know?"?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form, negative-raising

Well, we know *don't* is the same as *do not*, right?

Therefore, can I say "Do not you know?", instead of "Don't you know?"?

Well, I know that chances are I can't do that, but technically that should be correct, no?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Za2RGOY7SMc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should also be able to say 'Are I not?' instead of the typical 'Aren't I?' Presumably these colloquialisms result from the fact that neither 'Do you not know?' nor 'Am I not?' have a contraction that is at once easily pronounceable and logical.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the extraction of "Aren't I?" should be "Are not I" to follow the same "rules" as the OP use in the question, but the logic still stands.

Comment: I would expect "Aren't I?" to be correct English, not because "Are I not?" is correct English, but _because "Amn't I?" is ridiculously difficult to pronounce_. There are other cases of a language picking a somewhat-incorrect-but-easier-to-pronounce word. E.g. in French, the female possessive pronoun "sa" is changed to the male "son" _when "sa" would be hard to pronounce_. ("sa armoire" is grammatically correct, but "son armoire" is used because it doesn't suffer from the repeated "a" sound).

Comment: @Flater: that's why it used to be pronounced *"Ain't I?"*.

Comment: @PeterShor "Ain't" doesn't uniquely apply to the 1st person, since the same applies to 2nd/3rd person. You ain't, he ain't.

Comment: @Flater: it used to, a long time ago. But then people started using it for 2nd and 3rd persons, and after that it was deemed ungrammatical. So now we use *aren't*. [See etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ain't).

Answer (score 8):

Curiously, it is the same as

> Do you not know?

The words are transposed when the contraction comes in to make:

> Don't you know?

Sometimes, it is corrupted in the right order to:

> D'ya not know?

*D'ya* being pretty much single syllable when uttered.

I prefer the Scots version:

> Dinnae ken?

Comment: I prefer the Swahili version: Hamjui?

Comment: Or the French version: "Imbécile!"

Comment: @muntoo: I don't think that's a strict translation. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The raising of the negative from the subordinate verb "know" to the main verb "do" is known by (some) linguists as (variously) *not hopping*, *negative transportation*, and *neg raising*, and there's at four decades' worth of discussion as to what its rules are.  (This includes such things as what verbs are *neg-raising verbs* in various languages.)  Of course, when expanding it back out you have to "lower" the negative back down to the subordinate verb again.

One randomly chosen example of the literature in the field, that gives some pointers to others: [*The Syntax and Semantics of Neg-Raising, with Evidence from French*, Ellen F. Prince, *Language*, June 1976](http://jstor.org./pss/412568)

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no technical reason to *assume* this.

Whereas *do not* consists of two separate words, and only the "do" part is the "verb" for the purposes of inversion, in *couldn't*, *shouldn't*, *don't*, we can say that *-n't* is essentially a *clitic*, i.e. not a "word in its own right". (On phonological grounds, we might end up saying that *don't* is some kind of "fused" form standing in for a verb plus clitic.) A clitic is dependent upon a particular word, so that generally when that word moves, so does the clitic(s) dependent on it (like the "object pronouns" in Romance languages if you're familiar with them).

Answer (score 3):

Technically one could dissolve the contraction into "Do not you know?" but this would be an awkward construction, because English favors a negative after the subject and before the verb in this interrogative form, as in "Do you not know?"

Even this sounds a bit cumbersome given the contracted alternative. It may be used for emphasis, however, as in the following sentence:

"Do you *not* know how to do your own laundry after all these years?"

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some historical and lexicographic details. (the daily update is just too slow)

A hint is it isn’t *doont*, but *doe-nt* rhyming with *toe*.
*don't* and other auxiliary-clitic combinations are no longer ‘the sum of their parts’. They have diverged some centuries ago. It’s more obvious with *won't*, *ain't*, *mustn't* (*mussnt*).

There's no synchronic way to tell why it isn’t *willn’t*, *mustnt* or *doont* - other than learning those forms, consciously or unconsciously.

Good question, it’s one of the points that shows grammar isn’t as simple as a ‘technical’ or ‘logical’ combination of strings of phonemes (or letters if you prefer so).

The line of thought JdeBP hints to is right, but only if you **believe** in (sorry, I mean it like that) underlying structures, which often require a lot of language-specific fiddling, beating the purpose of descriptions of Language-in-General.