# Is "aren't you too old to be..." proper grammar?

Tags: apostrophe

My reasoning is that *aren't* stands for *are not* so the sentence would read *are not you too old to be...* which is not proper grammar.

Comment: 'Aren't you' is short for 'Are you not'.

Comment: See the examples here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aren-t

Comment: This has been covered here a lot from various angles. See, for example, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212680/why-do-not-we-ask-negative-questions-without-a-contraction-on-the-not-after-the, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225666/was-do-not-you-want-to-know-correct-200-years-ago-and-is-now-incorrect, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82982/why-does-why-doesnt-it-work-become-why-does-it-not-work

Answer (score 0):

A typo caused the confusion. Aren't does mean are not.  The sentence should read "Aren't you **too** old to be? rather than  *to old*.